# Looking High-res GameCenter Icon

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, game-center

I have been searching for a good quality (high-res) image of the GameCenter icon to implement in my app. I've seen this used in many professional games, and I am curious as to where I can find such an image.

I am not trying to violate any copyrights, but if these other apps are and have been using the icon for sometime now, Apple must not have a problem with it.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best one I could find from the iOS Dev Center. It's in JPEG format (**171 x 171**); if you need to have a transparent background, you can use Photoshop's background eraser tool, (or similar) to remove the background color.

[image]

http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/gamecenter/images/hero-gamecenter.jpg

Comment: Thanks! (If anyone can find a bigger one I will be sure to vote them up.)

Comment: I want to use this icon inside my app to link to the gamecenter leaderboard. Will apple approve this?

Comment: @alex: Probably, yes. But I recommend contacting the review team with this question to make sure.

Answer (score 9):

I created a vector mono version. http://eightbitstudios.com/bits/free-vector-based-ios-game-center-mono-icon

Comment: +1; Please consider attaching the image here for reference/use.

Comment: Has this been let through to the store?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a bigger png with transparency I just found:
http://meridimus.com/post/3901797112/heres-a-gamecenter-icon-i-made-500x500-because

Answer (score 2):

Game Center image of iOS Dev Center is updated to iOS7 version.. https://developer.apple.com/game-center/images/game-center-hero.png

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good one. Photoshop file included:

http://365psd.com/day/84/